# Unable to parse valid json file

Tags: javascript, json, ajax

### Logic

I've a JSON file as follows:

```
[
    {
        "title":"Article Title 1",
        "url":"https://mywebsite.com/articles/article1.html",
        "type":"codes"
    },
    {
        "title":"Article Title 2",
        "url":"https://mywebsite.com/articles/article2.html",
        "type":"games"
    },
    {
        "title":"Article Title 3",
        "url":"https://mywebsite.com/articles/article3.html",
        "type":"codes"
    }
]
```

And I'm reading this file, then populating my html page for each item in the file (so there are 3 titles, means 3 containers on my page).

### Problem

There was no error before, but now I get an error in console: `*SyntaxError: JSON.parse: expected ',' or ']' after array element at line 12 column 2 of the JSON data*`

BUT, it all works if there are only 2 articles! After adding the third dataset, there is error. The file format seems correct, there is "," at the right places, I converted it in different encodings but same error.

### Code

**Main Request**:

I'm requesting JSON file on document load like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var reqdata = new XMLHttpRequest();
    reqdata.open('GET', "https://website.com/dat/data.json");
    reqdata.onload = function() {
        if (reqdata.status >= 200 && reqdata.status < 400) {
            try{
                var postData = JSON.parse(reqdata.responseText);
                render_posts(postData); // this creates dynamic content in html
                //console.log(postData);
            } catch (err) {
                alert(" JSON Parse Error :'( ")
            }
        } else { alert("JSON Requestion Server Error!") }
    }; reqdata.onerror = function() { alert("JSON Request Connection Error!") };
    reqdata.send();
});
```

**Populating HTML**:

This is called from the code above if JSON.parse is working. This part works fine, just for reference..

```
function render_posts(data) {
    var htmldata = ""; var cardId = "";
    for (var x = 0; x < data.length; x++) {
        cardId = "card-type-" + data[x].type;
        htmldata += "<div class='card' id='" + cardId + "' onclick='card_clicker(\"" + data[x].url + "\")'><div class='header'>" + data[x].title + "</div><div class='decor'></div></div>";
    }
    cardWrapper.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', htmldata);
}
```

**Help**: Any help is appreciated.. Can't figure out what's the real problem. The JSON file looks fine. I tried formatting it online, but same results. I'm quite new to AJAX. Tried other solutions on stackoverflow but still the same..

Comment: Not a "fix" as such, but if you're using jQuery you can just do `$.getJSON('website.com/blah.json')` and it will handle the parsing for you. examples -> https://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/

Comment: There does not seem to be anything wrong. My best guess is that you are working with hardcoded test data, and there is some issue with the encoding or you have some unicode characters in there. For example characters that look like regular curly braces, but are in fact not.

Comment: I would try to copy&paste the responsetext into hex editor (like HxD) and search if there are any funny invisible characters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a small url decoding problem with JSON decode. Instead of adding the url like:

```
"url":"https://mywebsite.com/articles/article2.html"
```

It has to be given escape character backslash like this:

```
"url":"https:\/\/mywebsite.com\/articles\/article2.html"
```

And now everything is working fine!

Answer (score 0):

Probably hard to notice extra characters somewhere
or
non-standard double quotes used
or 
some other character that is not as you think it is (comma?)